# Load data get value using jquery and need to get div value on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()

{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds


<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
```

I want to get the value of load_Tweets ./these all code in js file I want to 
get the value of load_tweet in a variable and match the value like if value is 3 
then I disabled textarea .pls let me also know how to disabled the textarea its also created in js file too.

Comment: What do you mean by the value of load_tweet? Are you trying to grab the innerText of the div?

Answer (score 0):

By using the load function you are trying to load HTML from a remote file and inject it into the DOM. You can specify a callback function which executes when the request is complete for this.

To disable textarea

```
$("#yourtextareaid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and to re-enable it

```
$("#yourtextareaid").removeAttr("disabled");
```

***Edit:***

You can use the

[text()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text)

to extract the text inside the div.

Eg:

```
$("#yourtextareaid").text();
```